# How do I size a Google Search Results Window?

Tags: google-search

I have integrated a Custom Google Search on a new site I am working on. I have tried multiple ways to control the display size of the results window and it continually overrides those values.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="cse-search-results" style="width:700px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var googleSearchIframeName = "cse-search-results";
          var googleSearchFormName = "cse-search-box";
          var googleSearchFrameWidth = 700;
          var googleSearchDomain = "www.google.com";
          var googleSearchPath = "/cse";
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js"></script>
```

[Here is the link](http://yogahealthfoundation.org/search_results/) to the page - enter a search term to see the results. I would appreciate any assistance on getting this to display at 700px.

Comment: Why did you not change `googleSearchFrameWidth` to 700?

Comment: I tried 700 (and have edited my entry to reflect it) and it still displays the same way.

Comment: Does 700px act in the same way? Also, did you write this script yourself or did you use the default from the Google custom search engine? I only ask because the code you are showing is different from my site's search.

Comment: I loaded the new code and problem solved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Elevate your comment to an answer and I'll give you credit. Thanks.

Comment: No problem; please see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the new code from the Google Custom Searches? I would suggest trying this if you have not and if no other approaches work with your current code.

Good luck!